# Flow of Control between Handlers in Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, callback

I want to know why the following 2 codes are giving different outputs.

## Code 1:

```
const motherPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject(new Error("Milk has spilled due to overboiling"));
});

motherPromise.catch((rejectValue) => console.log("Hello"));
```

## Output of Code 1:

```
Hello
```

## Code 2:

```
const motherPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject(new Error("Milk has spilled due to overboiling"));
});

motherPromise.then((resolveValue) =>
  console.log(`${resolveValue} and Stove was shut`)
);
motherPromise.catch((rejectValue) => console.log("Hello"));
```

## Output of Code 2:

```
Hello
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Milk has spilled due to overboiling
    at app.js:2:10
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at app.js:1:23
```

What is the flow of control in both the codes and why is an extra Error being generated in the console for the second code?

Comment: The then path has dangling new promise that has the error as wel

Comment: @DanielA.White but if I am rejecting the promise and the "then" handler never runs and a new promise is never created then where is the extra Error being generated?

Comment: `.then()` ***ALWAYS*** creates a new promise. It's immediate, it doesn't only get executed if the promise you call it on is fulfilled. It's the handler itself that might or might not run depending on the state of the promise. But the `.then()` method itself is not conditional or delayed.

Comment: @VLAZ can you elaborate this a little more in depth. I didn't know this fact that ".then()" created a promise even when it is not executed.

Comment: That's all there is to it. If you have a promise `p` and call `p.then(/* whatever*/)` you get a new promise. In other words `p2 = p1.then(/*whatever*/)` results in there being two promises - `p1` the original  and `p2` the second one. If `.then()` *didn't* return a  promise, the  chains like `p.then(/* handler1 */).then(/* handler2 */)` etc. won't work at all. As *what* are you calling `then()` on if not a promise?

Comment: @VLAZ what about thenables? https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/thenable (just curious)

Comment: @VLAZ I understood this. Thank you. But I have one more question. Since the initial rejected promise is handled by the catch block, we see the output as "Hello" but now as you said that then() always returns a promise (even if in this case it is not executed) then the state of that promise should have been "pending" right ? And and and I still don't understand that if the isRejected() argument optional for then() and it's not even there in my code then if the initial promise was rejected it would only look for a catch() bloack right ? Then why is then() even executed here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox a generic thenable doesn't have to return a promise. Or return anything at all, it only needs to have a `.then()` method with two callback - first one for when it's fulfulled, the second one for when it is rejected. However, promises return promises from `.then()`.

Comment: @Intangible_pg18 the new promise returned from then will assume the state of the promise it was created from. `p2 = p1.then()` will *initially* create a pending promise (assuming `p1` is pending) but if `p1` gets rejected, then `p2` also gets rejected (which can trigger any `.catch()` handlers on `p2`). If `p1` is fulfilled, then `p2` will move to execute `.then()` handlers if any and would otherwise also be fulfilled.

Comment: @VLAZ okay now I got it. So is it right if I say that since the initial promise is rejected instantly (kind of synchronously) the code moves to the .then() statement and the returned new promise acquires the state of the initial promise that is right now rejected. Hence p2 is also a rejected promise which needs to be handled by a .catch(). Am I right? If yes, then if I encapsulate the initital rejection call in a setTimeout() of 5 seconds then the state of p1 would be pending at the time when the control would go to .then() and p2 will also acquire the "pending" state. Will it be so?

Comment: `.then()` is synchronous. The handler(s) added by it would be called later when the promise settles. It doesn't matter what the state of `p1` was, when and how it changed, `p2` will always end up in the same state. But might have different handlers attached. Since it doesn't have a `.catch()` handler in your case, then you get an unhandled promise rejection because *effectively* you have `p2 = p1.then(); p1.catch()` thus only the `p1` (`motherPromise`) rejection is handled, the rejection of `p2` (unnamed in your case but created from `motherPromise.then()`) is unhandled.

Comment: .then() is synchronous i.e. it will return a promise instantly acquiring the state of p1 as it is at that point so If I do `const motherPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(reject(new Error("Milk has spilled due to overboiling")),40000);
});` then the state of p1 would be pending at the point when .then() is executed right ? So it should return a "pending" promise (acquired from motherPromise).

Comment: The promise created by `.then()` will still get resolved or rejected the same way as the promise it was created from. If it was always pending then it would never settle therefore it would never execute any of its handlers.